# How to trigger IPv6 router solicitation on bridge slave port entering RUNNING state?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, ipv6, bridge, icmpv6

I have a small Linux system that runs a bridge `br0` between its wired `eth0` and wireless (AP mode) `wlan0` network interfaces.

For `br0` I have enabled IPv6 (stateless) autoconfiguration; this is actually handled by `dhcpcd`. Please note that `dhcpcd` is configured to do *stateless* autoconfiguration, *no stateful DHCPv6* anywhere to be seen.

As my system is kind of a diagnostics tool for IPv6, I switch it on a regular basis between different IPv6 networks (subnets): pull the cable at the switch, plug it into another port.

The problem with this setup now is: `eth0` is a slave interface to the bridge `br0`. When I plug in the cable into `eth0` (and the switch) this now **does not trigger any IPv6 router solicitations**. The reason seems to be that `br0` never sees any transitions to or from RUNNING with the exception when it is initially brought up. Restarting `br0` is not an option.

How can I configure `br0` or `eth0` to initiate IPv6 router solicitations when `eth0` enters RUNNING state, that is, when I plug in an Ethernet cable (on *both* ends, of course)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only "solution", or rather hack, I've found so far is to enable SLAAC on the `eth0` bridge port network interface, using `/etc/network/interfaces`. For this, add:

```
iface eth0 inet6 auto
```

Since this uses `/etc/network/interface`, it will configure the Linux kernel. Please note that I'm **not using** `dhcpcd` here and thus `dhcpcd` needs to be told to keep it fingers off `eth0`; this is necessary for bridge port network interfaces anyway. So,  `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` has to contain:

```
denyinterfaces eth0
```

In this configuration the Linux kernel will automatically issue RS router solicitations when `eth0` comes online ("carrier"). And this is what is needed. The resulting RA router advertisements are (also) multicast, thus also autoconfiguring the bridge interface `br0` as intended. That `eth0` also gets autoconfigured is just a byproduct.